# Implementing fancybox onclick()

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

```
<?php
   echo '<td class="options-width">'.
        '<a href="edituser_lightbox.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . ' " onclick:"  $.fancybox({ href:'example.jpg',title : 'Custom Title'});"title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip" </a>'.
        '<a href="deleteuser.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . ' " class="icon-2 info-tooltip">   </a>'.
        '<a href="" title="Save" class="icon-5 info-tooltip">     </a>'.
        '</td>';


   echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```

I have to atleast be close here guys? Can you see what im trying to do? I can't change my css to include fancybox either :(

Comment: For repeated echoes like that, you really SHOULD break out of PHP (`?>`) mode, or at least use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo:

```
onclick:"
```

Make the colon an equal sign:

```
onclick="
```

Also, ensure that the object's attributes' values will be strings by adding quotation marks.

```
onclick='$.fancybox({href: "'example.jpg'", title: "'Custom Title'"});'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` attribute should be specified with an `=`, not `:` as in:

```
echo '<a href="edituser_lightbox.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '" onclick="$.fancybox({ href:\'example.jpg\',title : \'Custom Title\'});" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip" </a>';
```

Inside the fancybox statement, you will also need to backslash-escape the single quotes so they are presented as literal `'` in the output HTML. You also had an extra space before the closing `"` in the `href=` attribute.

It is not considered good practice to place the JavaScript inline inside the tag. Instead it would be better to bind it as in:

```
$("a#editLink").click(function() {
   $.fancybox({ href:'example.jpg',title : 'Custom Title'});
});
```

Note, you would need to add the `id="editLink"` to the `<a>` tag. (It could be any id, or various other jQuery selectors instead of an `id`.

```
echo '<a id="editLink" href="edituser_lightbox.php?user_id=' . $row['user_id'] . '" onclick="$.fancybox({ href:\'example.jpg\',title : \'Custom Title\'});" title="Edit" class="icon-1 info-tooltip" </a>';
```

Comment: @user1576685 What didn't work? You need to be more descriptive than that. What output did it produce? Did you debug it in your browser's console?